# Перемещение блока после каждого 3 элемента (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть блок с N элементами и 1 блоком, необходимо, чтобы при клике на этот элемент, под него перемещался блок, который в данный момент имеет свойство display: none;

Мой код перемещает блок каждый раз после 6 элемента: http://jsfiddle.net/Qe9sS/1/

Нужно, чтобы при клике на первый, второй, третий элемент - блок переместился под третий, при клике на четвертый, пятый, шестой - под шестой, и так далее.

В оригинальном варианте элементы выстроены по 3 на линию, то есть, примерно в таком виде:

```
элемент №1 элемент №2 элемент №3
элемент №4 элемент №5 элемент №6
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вы просто перемудрили, вот пример:

```
var $bdetail = $(".b-detail"),$links=$(".content-item > a");
$(".content-item").on('click','> a',function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var index=parseInt($links.index(this)/3+1)*3;
    index=index>$links.length?$links.length:index;
    index--;        
    var $that=$links.eq(index);
    if (!$that.next().is($bdetail)) {
        $bdetail.stop().slideUp('fast', function () {
            $bdetail.slideDown('slow').insertAfter($that);
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Qe9sS/8/

Comment: @eicto, спасибо за Ваш ответ, но, нужно, чтобы при клике на первый, второй, третий элемент - блок (b-detail) переместился под третий, при клике на четвертый, пятый, шестой - под шестой, и так далее. То есть, например, 6 элементов выстроены в два ряда, при клике на первые три - он перемещается под первый ряд, по последним трем - под второй ряд.

Comment: @Fishy  исправил, думаю на этот раз как вы хотели.

Comment: @eicto, большое спасибо! Кстати, странная особенность, если нажать на 7 элемент - ничего не происходит, а если, например, нажать на 6, а после на 7, то после 7 все отлично выдвигается.

Comment: это потому-что в разметке оно стоит в конце, поставьте появляющийся элемент перед ссылками вообще, и все будет нормально. вот так даже
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Qe9sS/9/ ну и соответственно если будете его прятать, то паркуйте куда нить за пределы блока .content-item, типа `$('body').append($bdetail)`;

Comment: @eicto, отлично, еще раз спасибо!